# Can you use a @Helper inside an @Helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-declarative-helpers

I am not sure this is possible.

I have a bunch of `@Helper`'s inside a view AND in other views:

```
@helper ViewHelper1()
{
   ...
}
@helper ViewHelper2()
{
   ...
}
etc.
```

I have repetitive code that is used in the view AND in other views:

```
@if (!(Model.Entity == Model.Enum.One))
    {
        <td>
            @ViewHelper1()
        </td>
    }
    else
    { 
        <td>
            @ViewHelper1()
        </td>
        <td>
            @ViewHelper1()
        </td>
    }
```

The actual `@ViewHelper1` has more complex code, but that's not important (I think).

Well, since each view has a number of `@Helper`'s (30+ views, 10-15 `@Helper`'s each) and the `<table>` structure is the same, I was wondering how to go about creating a `@Helper` in `App_Code` that encapsulates the `<td>` structure and then would pass the view's `@Helper`.

Say:

```
@helper Table(...) 
    {
        ...
    }
```

Or whether or not that's even possible and then call it in the view like:

```
@Table(HelperView1)
```

If it is I just needed help with the syntax.

As always, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated razor helpers are just functions with the return type `HelperResult`.
You can have delegates which returns `HelperResult` as parameters in your main helper and call them at the appropriate places.

A small sample to get you started:

```
@helper View1()
{
    <h1>View1</h1>
}

@helper View2()
{
    <h2>View2</h2>
}

@helper Table(Func<HelperResult> viewHelper)
{
    <text>Reuslt of viewHelper</text>
    @viewHelper()
}

@Table(View1)
@Table(View2)
```

The generated output:

```
Reuslt of viewHelper
<h1>View1</h1>

Reuslt of viewHelper
<h2>View2</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to figure out `Func<T, TResult>` and stupidly didn't realize I didn't need two parameters. +1 for the code sample.

Comment: Follow-up question: If I put `@helper Table(...)` in a file in `App_Code` and then try to, say call `Model.Entity` through an `if` statement I obviously get a "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference". I understand why I would get that error, but is there a way around that error? Or is it a limitation? Thank you again.

Comment: I think this a limitation of putting the helpers in `App_Code` what you can try is to pass the Model through another parameter to your `Table` like `@helper Table(dynamic model, Func<HelperResult> otherHelper)`